# How to format date like "1344991242000" in php

Tags: php, datetime, date-formatting

I am trying to format date using following function but getting out put

44591-01-28 07:20:00

```
$timestamp="1344991242000";

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp);    // outputs 44591-01-28 07:20:00
```

Comment: @chris85 I was able to replicate it here https://3v4l.org/WsJ0g

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Where are you getting `$timestamp="1344991242000";`? Since `strtotime('2015-12-15 06:22:21') == 1450156941`, your `$timestamp` value is not what you think it is - see https://3v4l.org/nFmXX

Comment: it must be of year 2015  so this output is wrong

Comment: sorry buudy i have wrongly commented that date ..actually i am getting this date in meetup response so i have to convert it into datetime .so as per my posts it must belong to current year

Comment: So you want to find a way to convert `1344991242000` so that it returns `2015-12-15 06:22:21`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in milliseconds. Divide by 1000:

```
$timestamp = "1344991242000";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp / 1000);
// 2012-08-14 17:40:42
```

Comment: this is probably the correct answer, although the OP states that it is a 2015 date, not 2012, in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34281469/how-to-format-date-like-1344991242000-in-php#comment56304690_34281484).

Comment: If it is a timestamp then is is definitely in milliseconds. The date that is produces is, what it is. Maybe the questioner is mistaken about what they expect it to be.

Comment: i thik you are right buddy ..thanks for the reply its in miliseconds hope so. as i am getting it in meetup api  response . again thanks ..:)

Comment: @yogendrayaduvanshi per meetup API -http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/open_events/ `by absolute time in milliseconds since the epoch` so seems correct (I don't know exact function you're using but I'd presume this is the same across their system; defer to their API docs though).